# WinJS, display image from a byte array?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm looking for a way to display a JPEG image stored in a byte array. This is a Windows 8 Store App built in Javascript. The byte array is returned from a C# WinRT component. Its type in C# is `byte[]`.

Basically, what I want is to get an object so that I can call:

```
URL.createObjectURL(bytearray, {oneTimeOnly: true});
```

upon. Currently this generates a runtime error because the array interface is not supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked about WinJS.xhr : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh868282.aspx

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not looking for ways to download or transfer the file. How is xhr helpful in my case? The image is not from the web.

Comment: I am not pro in WinJS though, I found file to byte array solution, it might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004190/file-to-byte-array-in-winjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered a far easier method.

```
var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "image/jpg"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob, { oneTimeOnly: true });
```

`Blob` is actually supported directly by `URL.createObjectURL`. The only catch is that you have to specify a mime format to identify the buffer format, which in my case is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Current solution I found is quite round about. Hence, before giving the solution for bytes to URL, few comments:

1. If there is better way to get to DOM stream/blob object from bytes, try out.
2. If you control the winrt component - check if you can return StorageFile object. In that case - code will simplifyto

   var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(storageFile);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });

now solution:

```
var bytes;
var memoryStream;    
var streams = Windows.Storage.Streams;
{

    // get IBuffer out of bytes
    var dataWriter = new streams.DataWriter();
    dataWriter.writeBytes(bytes);
    var buffer = dataWriter.detachBuffer();
    dataWriter.close();

    // get IInputStream out of IBuffer
    memoryStream = new streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    return memoryStream.writeAsync(buffer);
}).then(function onmemorystreamwritecomplete()
{
    var inputStream = memoryStream.getInputStreamAt(0);

    // get DOM MSStream from IInputStream
    var domMStream = MSApp.createStreamFromInputStream('image/jpg', inputStream);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(domMStream, { oneTimeOnly: true });
    memoryStream.close();
    test3Img.setAttribute('src', url);
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the solution. I do have control of the C# WinRT component. Is the conversion procedure same as this? And why would you recommend doing it in the component, is it a performance issue?

Comment: keeping things simple always helps. this code snippet does bytes -> IBuffer -> IInputStream -> MSStream -> URL whereas other one can do StorageFile->File->URL . btw, is there a reason to read bytes from file in c# winrt component. it can be done in the js code.