# WinJS: IInputStream from String

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

In a situation where I have a string in memory and want to send it to a web service using `BackgroundUploader`, I want to avoid having to write it to disk (and thus handling cleanup of temp files).

Now there's [`createUploadFromStreamAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.createuploadfromstreamasync.aspx) for that but I wonder what's the most performant way to create the required `IInputStream` from a String.

The first thing I thought of was to convert it to an `IBuffer` using `CryptographicBuffer::convertStringToBinary`, write it into an [`InMemoryRandomAccessStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx) and get the IInputStream from there. So it's String -> IBuffer -> InMemoryRandomAccessStream -> IInputStream. Quite a hassle...

The second way to accomplish would be to do sth like `new Blob(myString.split('')).msDetachStream().getInputStreamAt(0)` which of course doesn't use as many native calls and has the same number of steps. I.e. String -> Array -> Blob -> IInputStream.

What would be your approach to handling this conversion?

Comment: this question may give some [lead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862421/winjs-display-image-from-a-byte-array/15863667#15863667) to solution.

Comment: yes, that's what I propose in my first approach

Comment: is there need for the split call in second approach? I read [blob documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FBlob) - will this not be ok? `var blob = new Blob([myString]).msDetachStream().getInputStreamAt(0);`

Comment: Good call, I'll give it a try! I wonder whether the JS engine will operate on the original string or if it will create a copy, too...

Answer (score 0):

A tested and working version to replace method 1 which should not be using CryptographicBuffers in this scenario is:

```
                    var randomAccessStream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                    var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(randomAccessStream);
                    dataWriter.unicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf8;
                    dataWriter.byteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.littleEndian;
                    dataWriter.writeString(myString);
                    dataWriter.storeAsync().then(function () {
                        return dataWriter.flushAsync();
                    }).then(function () {
                        var stream = dataWriter.detachStream();
                        stream.seek(0);
                        dataWriter.close();
                        stream;
                    });
```

A tested and working version of method 2 is simply: new Blob([new Uint8Array(Array.from(myString))]).msDetachStream().getInputStreamAt(0)

The stream byte order and encoding could make a significant difference depending how you use it.  In fact the second method may need to use another way to split the string depending on the encoding format.